# SharePoint 2010 Resource Calendar Column Problem

Tags: content-type, site-column, resources

I have 2 calendars on the same site:  A production calendar and a test calendar.  The test calendar was created to demonstrate the resource reservation system, and works as desired.  However, when attempting to add the content types to the existing production calendar, the Resources column (of type Resource Field) was not added to the calendar.  What I've tried so far:

- To add it manually (but it the Resources column is not available under Site Columns, nor is the Resources Field type available as a selection for a new column type).
- To remove the content types and re-add them to the calendar list (still no luck).
- To deactivate and reactive the Group Work Lists feature (still nothing).

Other than blowing away the existing calendar and recreating it, is there another way to get the Resources column added to the existing calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the list that you want to add the column to:
List Settings --> Title, description and navigation
Select the option to use this calendar for Resource Reservations.
(If you do not see this option, then you need to go to Site Settings --> Manage Site Features and turn on Group Work Lists. If you do not see that feature, your admin needs to turn it on in the Site Collection Features.)

Once you turn on this setting, it will change the default view of the calendar, so just go back in and turn this setting OFF.  The columns will stay.